# Apache Kafka picks up additional traffic

Tags: python, apache-kafka, network-traffic

I am using Kafka to monitor logs for traffic. However, since the server is used for other projects, I am picking up additional traffic in the logs, not only for this topic but it seems somehow I pick up all of it.

How can this be? Isn't the consumer suppose to read only a specific topic? Also all of it comes on partition 0. I am not sure this is important or not. I am new to Kafka. Thanks and regards,

The consumer is setup as follows:

```
self.__traffic_consumer = KafkaConsumer(  
                 'ai',  #Topic
                 bootstrap_servers = ['10.5.1.1:9094'],  
                 auto_offset_reset = 'earliest',  
                 enable_auto_commit = True,  
                 #group_id = 'ai-mining_group',  
                 value_deserializer = lambda x : loads(x.decode('utf-8')),
                 consumer_timeout_ms = 1000,
                 )
```

Comment: Please show the logs you're referring to

Comment: In this particular case, unfortunately, i cannot share the content of the logs. However, I am not sure it is needed. The question about the topic may be more general and similar to other types of logs, not only to traffic logs.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by "traffic logs". AFAIK, `kafka-python` doesn't emit TCP trace logs on the consumer client, let alone put them into the topic(s) on its own. Your shown code **does** read from a specific topic, and all partitions of it. You should see the same with `kafka-console-consumer --topic ai`, too, so its unclear if you are looking for a Python solution, or not

Comment: I see. To clarify this, the setup runs the following: TCP-replay of PCAP files simulating traffic --> Zeek conn_log --> Kafka. The arrows show how the information flow all the way to Kafka.

Comment: Okay, so start with the basics... Does `kafka-console-consumer --topic ai` show the same data as the python consumer? If so, the problem isn't the Python code. If you need to filter some data, you either need to do that "upstream" in your replay tool, or add some conditional inside the consumer code

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think additional traffic was logged since the topic was used by other users as well. The ```kafka-console-consumer.sh``` shows the same thing. This explains at least in part my issue. To solve this, I can set the auto reset offset to "latest". I have additional setup problems but I will open a new question for that.